# Are there simple way to receive Map instead of List when using Spring JdbcTemplate.query?

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

`getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(sql, getMapper());` returns List, but I need a Map where key will be store data of one of the field of object. For example, I have object named "Currency" which has fields: id, code, name, etc. Code above will return List object, but I want to get currency by id from Map. Now, I wrote the following code:

```
@Override
public Map<Integer, Currency> listCurrencies() {
    String sql = "select cur_id, cur_code, cur_name ... from currencies";

    List<Currency> currencies = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(sql, getMapper());
    Map<Integer, Currency> map = new HashMap<Integer, Currency>(currencies.size());

    for (Currency currency : currencies) {
        map.put(currency.getId(), currency);
    }

    return map;
}
```

Are there any way to do same but without creating List object and looping inside it?

Answer (score 2):

You have `ResultSetExtractor` for extracting values from the `ResultSet`. So in your case you can write a custom ResultSetExtractor which will return you the Map object.